# Usage on Patindex() function

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using `patindex` for pattern search of "MD" or "DO". The below statement returns `3`.
Am I using it in the wrong way or is there another way of checking condition?

```
select PATINDEX ('%[MD,DO]%','FHoisegh MD')
```

Comment: `PATINDEX` doesn't have any kind of alternation operator you would need to use CLR and Regex for this or two expressions

Comment: @Ratz My answer does not work, as indicated in the comments.  If you could unaccept my answer, I can delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select PATINDEX ('%[MD][DO]%','FHoisegh MD')  -- returns 10
```

As you have it in your question, it is looking for any of the 5 characters between the square brackets, and finds 'o' at position 3.  For example,

```
select PATINDEX ('%[MD,DO]%','F,Hoisegh MD')  -- returns 2
```

As @Filip De Vos pointed out, `'%[MD][DO]%'` will also match `MO`.  The only way I can think of to handle this would be to subtract out the index for `MO`:

```
select PATINDEX ('%[MD][DO]%','FHoisegh MO') - PATINDEX('%MO%', 'FHoisegh MO') -- returns 0
```

If `MD` and `DO` are the only terms you'll be searching for, this might suffice.  For anything else, I'd say look for other ways to do it.

Comment: So in your solution it will find `MO` also.

Comment: What numeric result in your new version indicates success? `ALMODOVAR` contains `DO` but your new version returns `0`

Answer (score 3):

```
select T.Value
from (values
        (charindex('MD', 'FHoisegh MD')),
        (charindex('DO', 'FHoisegh MD'))
     ) as T(Value)
where T.Value > 0
```

Answer (score 2):

With a combination of PATINDEX/CHARINDEX, NULLIF & ISNULL functions you can get the desired result:

```
DECLARE @text VARCHAR(100) = 'FHoisegh MXD';
SELECT ISNULL( NULLIF(PATINDEX('%MD%',@text),0), PATINDEX('%DO%',@text) )
```

If you search for three or more values (ex. DO / RE / MI) instead of ISNULL function can be used COALESCE function:

```
DECLARE @text VARCHAR(100) = 'abcMODOKO';
SELECT COALESCE( NULLIF(PATINDEX('%DO%',@text),0), NULLIF(PATINDEX('%RE%',@text),0), PATINDEX('%MI%',@text) )
```