# SQL select to get a string between two spaces

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, substring

I have a field with names in the format DOE JOHN HOWARD or DOE JOHN H.

I need a query to get the string between the two spaces (JOHN in this case).

[The SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362260/a-sql-query-to-select-a-string-between-two-known-strings) shows how to do that when the desired substring is between two **different** strings, but I don't see how to apply something similar when the desired substring is between two instances of the same string (a space in this case).

How can I do that?

Comment: In the case of George Herbert Walker Bush, what do you want to return?

Comment: @AlexWeitzer : Okay, there's no need to bring politics into this discussion - things are confusing enough as it is! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way:

```
select 
left(substring(fld, 
    charindex(' ', fld) + 1, len(fld)), 
    charindex(' ', substring(fld, charindex(' ', fld) + 2, len(fld))))
```

Comment: Nice! Worked perfectly. Ty.

Answer (score 8):

There is a somewhat sneaky way you could do this using [PARSENAME.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx)

It's intended purpose is to get particular parts of an object/namespace, however, in this case you could use it by replacing the strings with periods first.

E.g.,

```
SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE('DOE JOHN HOWARD',' ','.'),2)
```

Comment: I appreciate. This is simply superb. Btw in my situation the above accepted answer did not work. But Your answer did the trick... Thanks.

Comment: Neat trick! If people are planning to use this, check the documentation on PARSENAME first and it'll only work for strings with 4 parts or less.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some searches to resolve my problem, realised there is no generic answer, so below is piece of code to find string between some other strings. I think it may be useful for somebody in future.

```
DECLARE @STRING NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Something here then stringBefore Searching stringAfter something there.'
DECLARE @FIRST NVARCHAR(20) = 'stringBefore'
DECLARE @SECOND NVARCHAR(20) = 'stringAfter'
DECLARE @SEARCHING NVARCHAR (20)

SET @SEARCHING = (SELECT SUBSTRING(@STRING, CHARINDEX(@FIRST, @STRING) + LEN(@FIRST), CHARINDEX(@SECOND, @STRING) - CHARINDEX(@FIRST, @STRING) - LEN(@FIRST))) 
-- if you want to remove empty spaces
SET @SEARCHING = REPLACE(@SEARCHING, ' ', '')
SELECT @SEARCHING
```

Then output as below:

(No column name)

Searching