# SQL Select between two spaces or everything after first if only one

Tags: sql-server-2012, substring

I have a column that contains the description of a group each row looks something like on of the two options below with a varying number of words and or numbers in place of blah:

```
bla1h bla2h blah blah Group 18956
blah bl4ah blah Group 189 bla5h
```

I am needed to extract the numbers after the word group.

I was able to come up with this code:

```
SUBSTRING(R.GroupDescription,CHARINDEX('Group ',R.GroupDescription),20)
```

This will trim it one of the below:

```
Group 18956
Group 189 blah
```

After this I need to trim it further so I was able to come up with the below code thanks to [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172378/sql-select-to-get-a-string-between-two-spaces):

```
LEFT(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(R.GroupDescription,CHARINDEX('Group ',R.GroupDescription),20),CHARINDEX(' ',SUBSTRING(R.GroupDescription,CHARINDEX('Group ',R.GroupDescription),20)) +1,LEN(SUBSTRING(R.GroupDescription,CHARINDEX('Group ',R.GroupDescription),20))),CHARINDEX(' ',SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(R.GroupDescription,CHARINDEX('Group ',R.GroupDescription),20), CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(R.GroupDescription,CHARINDEX('Group ',R.GroupDescription),20)) +2, LEN(SUBSTRING(R.GroupDescription,CHARINDEX('Group ',R.GroupDescription),20)))))
```

This code is both cumbersome and only works on the second example from above in the first example where there is nothing after the set of numbers I want It returns nothing.

Also the real fun part of this is the returned result is going to be needed to do a join to another table.

I am using SSMS 2012 with a SQL Server 2012 back end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way assuming there is a single `Group` always followed by a number:

```
;WITH R(GroupDescription) AS (
    SELECT 'blah blah blah blah Group 18956' UNION
    SELECT 'blah blah blah Group 189 blah' 
)
SELECT LEFT(T.F, CHARINDEX(' ', T.F + ' ') - 1) VAL
FROM (SELECT
    SUBSTRING(R.GroupDescription, CHARINDEX('Group ',R.GroupDescription) + 6, LEN(R.GroupDescription)) F
    FROM R) T
```

---

```
VAL
18956
189
```

Comment: Yes There will only error be a single Group in the string of text. However the info I need retrieved is the number after it. That number can vary in length from 4 to 7 numbers and I will be using that result to form a join to another table. I was unable to get your code to work for me. But thank you for trying.

Comment: This works but I am unsure how to use the results as a join to another table. Table R should join Table G on R.results from above = G.GroupID

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would benefit from a function that will strip all non 0-9 chars from your long string.  This would leave only the numbers and then you can join on that to your tables.

```
CREATE FUNCTION strip_function (@value VARCHAR(200)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(200)
AS 
BEGIN

WHILE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @value) > 0 
SET @value = REPLACE(@value, SUBSTRING(@value, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @value),1),'')

RETURN @value 
END 
GO 

SELECT dbo.strip_function(your_column)
FROM your_table
```

Comment: That helps but does not solve it all the way as while i did not say this before the blah's could have numbers in them. However you could not know that I am sorry. I will edit the question to include that as a possibility. This answer is still useful.