# How to get text between two words/characters

Tags: sql-server

How can I get some text between two known words?

Sub-select example:

```
(SELECT TOP(1)Note
FROM Clients
WHERE (ID=@ID) AND (Note IS NOT NULL) AND (Note NOT LIKE '%Damaged%')) AS Note
```

This returns:

```
Blablabla bla bla blabla bla bla bla (21.08.2015) "some text" word bla bla
Blablabla bla bla blabla bla bla bla (25.08.2015) "another text" word bla bla 
Blablabla bla bla blabla bla bla bla (28.08.2015) "TEXT I NEED TO GET" word bla bla blabla bla bla.
```

So I need to get text between last ")" and last "word"

Tried some magic but it didn't work with last ")" and last "word"

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server? (TOP...)

Comment: Yeah standart SQL server, no MySQL and no Oracle.

Comment: Standard SQL (i.e. ANSI SQL) <> SQL Server.

Comment: Go [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362260/a-sql-query-to-select-a-string-between-two-known-strings) and sort your query

Comment: Tried, but didnt find out how to get text between last words only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys I found my own solution:

> DECLARE @S VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Blablabla bla bla blabla bla bla bla
>   (21.08.2015) "some text" word bla bla Blablabla bla bla blabla bla bla
>   bla (25.08.2015) "another text" word bla bla  Blablabla bla bla blabla
>   bla bla bla (28.08.2015) "TEXT I NEED TO GET" word bla bla blabla bla
>   bla.'
>
> SELECT LEFT(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@S), CHARINDEX(')', REVERSE(@S)) -
>   2))+'word', CHARINDEX('word',REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@S), CHARINDEX(')',
>   REVERSE(@S)) - 2))+'word')-1) AS respond

This returns exactly:

> "TEXT I NEED TO GET"

Thank you all for leading me to this point.

Comment: Hi, your easier solution is quite the same as mine. The most important difference is, that you use the same function calls repeatedly. My approach with the `CROSS APPLY` is - at least in my eyes - much easier to read, due to the fact, that interimistic results are used with a *name* while you have a deeply nested *function-in-function-in-repeated-function* code. You use two times `LEFT` while I use `SUBSTRING` and calculate the length. What you take as *easier* is personal opinion. I would not like to maintain your function in some months :-)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

You try to find the *last occurence*. This is the first in a reverted string...

--This is a mockup of your table to hold your strings:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(YourLine VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('Blablabla bla bla blabla bla bla bla (21.08.2015) "some text" word bla bla')
,('Blablabla bla bla blabla bla bla bla (25.08.2015) "another text" word bla bla') 
,('Blablabla bla bla blabla bla bla bla (28.08.2015) "TEXT I NEED TO GET" word bla bla blabla bla bla.');
```

--Here I specify the word you are searching for

```
DECLARE @SearchWord VARCHAR(100)='word';
```

--This is the query

```
SELECT REVERSE(C.CutOut) AS YourSnippet
FROM @tbl AS tbl
```

--`CROSS APPLY` works row-wise: Take the current line and revert it!

```
CROSS APPLY(SELECT REVERSE(tbl.YourLine) AS RevLine) AS A
```

--Find the **first** occurence of `)` and the **first** occurence of the **reverted searchword**!

```
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CHARINDEX(')',A.RevLine) AS PosParanthesis
                  ,CHARINDEX(REVERSE(@SearchWord),A.RevLine) AS PosWord) AS B
```

--Cut the string at the position found to the length calculated

```
CROSS APPLY(SELECT SUBSTRING(A.RevLine,B.PosWord + LEN(@SearchWord)+1,B.PosParanthesis-B.PosWord-LEN(@SearchWord)-1) AS CutOut) AS C
```

The result of the las `CROSS APPLY` is your target string, but reverse. Therefore a last reverse in the main `SELECT`...

Comment: The +1 and -1 in the SUBSTRING removes the space after 'word' in the result. You could argue that this space should be included and thus remove the +1 and -1. This would make results with @SearchWord = 'ord' include the w.

Comment: It looks so complicated.

Comment: Hi @J.Adam, this is not complicated at all... The key is my second line about string reversion. `REVERSE('hello')` returns `olleh`. See my edits

Comment: Thank you for reply. But I found "easier" way.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @start varchar(100)
set @start = 'startword'

declare @end varchar(100)
set @end = 'endword'

SELECT TOP(1) Note , substring( LEFT(note, charindex(@end, note, CHARINDEX(@start, note))-1), CHARINDEX(@start, note) + len(@start), LEN(note))   result
FROM Clients
WHERE (ID=@ID) AND (Note IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Looks great but it returns only first case of my text between #start and #end. How can I get last one?

Comment: last means the end word ?

Comment: Text I need is between last ")" and last "word". Yours query returns text between first ")" and first "word". If you change only end word it will return everything between last "word" and fist ")" right? But I have also notes where is only one ")" and one "word". But when is there more, still need last one.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @id int , ,
    @sword varchar(30) ,
    @delimiter varchar(30) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) , id int
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    declare @start1 varchar(100)
    set @start1 = @sword

    declare @end1 varchar(100)
    set @end1 =  @delimiter
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) + Len(@delimiter) - 1
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata , id)  
        VALUES(substring( LEFT((SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)), charindex(@end1, (SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)), CHARINDEX(@start1, (SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start))))-1), CHARINDEX(@start1, (SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start))) + len(@start1), LEN((SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start))))  ,@id ) 

        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)+ Len(@delimiter) - 1
         END 
    RETURN 
END

Select note , fnSplitString (note , id ,'startword', 'endword') from clients
```

Comment: I have created a function which should split your string using the end word  and then trying to take value between first and last. See if it works for u . Thanks

Comment: This is procedural thinking an way to complicated. You really should avoit loops where you don't need them...

Comment: Thank you for reply. But I found "easier" way.