# Extract right string between last two parentheses

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to extract the values inside the last parentheses of each row.
Column *Name* is what I have and column *ID* is what I need.

Notice that row 2 has two set of parentheses and that one row has no parentheses.

[image: ![enter image description here]

I tried using this script:

```
SUBSTRING(name,CHARINDEX('(',name)+1 ,CHARINDEX(')',name)-CHARINDEX('(',name)-1)
```

The script returns error message *Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.* because of the the third row has no parentheses.

Comment: Does the `ID` you want to extract always in the last of the string?

Comment: How many times will you ask the same question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find values in between two characters '(' and ')'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55307313/find-values-in-between-two-characters-and)

Comment: @Sami your solution was good I think, why did you delete ..?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Cuase it's the same as Gordon solution and I did not see his post when post mine ;)

Comment: @Sami ooh, OK didn't notice the reverse in Gordon's solution.

Comment: @Sami - Yes the ID I want to extract is the last in the string.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Ok, Undeleted and add more :)

Comment: @Smor - it is a different question. Please read the question carefully.
Furthermore, contribution in this forum is voluntary. You do not need to participate.

Answer (score 4):

For your sample data, this should do what you want:

```
select replace(right(name, charindex('(', reverse(name) + '(') - 1), ')', '')
```

Comment: This solution did not work. I get the following error message: "Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function."

Comment: @user716255 . . . That would only occur if you have examples with no parentheses -- and there are no such examples in your question.

Comment: The example I gave was strip down version of a much larger data set. I forgot to mentioned there were nulls in the data set. 

I have tried using:

 case 
 when name is null then ''
 else replace(right(name, charindex('(', reverse(name)) - 1), ')', '')
end
I get the same error: Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function.

Comment: @user716255 . . . Did you notice that I fixed the code?

Answer (score 2):

Since the `ID` is always the last one

```
SELECT *,
       REPLACE(RIGHT(Str, CHARINDEX('(', REVERSE(Str)) - 1), ')', '')
FROM (
       VALUES ('Smith, Donald R.(Don) (NBK1234)'), 
              ('Rogers, Bob (A1234457)'),
              ('Rogers, Bob (A1234457)(A1B2)')
     ) T(Str);
```

**Returns:**

```
+---------------------------------+----------+
|               Str               |    ID    |
+---------------------------------+----------+
| Smith, Donald R.(Don) (NBK1234) | NBK1234  |
| Rogers, Bob (A1234457)          | A1234457 |
| Rogers, Bob (A1234457)(A1B2)    | A1B2     |
+---------------------------------+----------+
```

If the `ID` you want to extract is not always in the end, but always is the only string has numbers then

```
SELECT *,
       REPLACE(REVERSE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Str),PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(Str)), CHARINDEX('(', REVERSE(Str))-1), '(', '')), ' ', '')
FROM (
       VALUES ('Smith, Donald R.(Don) (NBK1234)'), 
              ('Rogers, Bob (A1234457)'),
              ('Rogers, Bob (A1234457)(not an id)')
     ) T(Str);
```

**Returns:**

```
+-----------------------------------+----------+
|                Str                |    ID    |
+-----------------------------------+----------+
| Smith, Donald R.(Don) (NBK1234)   | NBK1234  |
| Rogers, Bob (A1234457)            | A1234457 |
| Rogers, Bob (A1234457)(not an id) | A1234457 |
+-----------------------------------+----------+
```

See how it's working in a **[Live Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9c196371ed1c2b350a7fd01c812402ae)**

Comment: I think your suggestion might work. TRIM(REVERSE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Str),PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(Str)), CHARINDEX('(', REVERSE(Str))-1), '(', '')))
Note, I am running SQL Server 2014. TRIM was introduce in 2017. Can you modify your example for 2014?

Answer (score 1):

For your data . I hope below query will help you .

```
select name ,CASE WHEN RIGHT(name,1) <> ')' THEN '' ELSE 
REPLACE(RIGHT(name ,CHARINDEX ('(' ,REVERSE(name))),'))',')') END ID
from yourtable
```