# how to dynamically find and replace the function text

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have 800+ functions in my database. I would need to modify their source databases dynamically and create snapshots.

example of the function:

```
create function [schema1].[funTest1] (@param1 varchar(50))

returns table as
return    
(
select * from [curr_database1].[schema1].[funTest1](@param1)

union

select * from [curr_database2].[schema1].[funTest1](@param1)

)
```

I want to change the script as:

```
 create or alter function [schema1].[funTest1] (@param1 varchar(50))

    returns table as return

    (        
    select * from [new_database2].[schema1].[funTest1](@param1)

    union

    select * from [new_database3].[schema1].[funTest1](@param1)

    )
```

basically, I got all the functions script using the sys.syscomments. I'm looking for an option to find and replace the database dynamically to create the snapshots.

How can I get it? Thank you!

Here is the sample code that I have developed for sharing. All the database in the functions starts with the same text(for ex. "curr"). Please share your thoughts. Thanks in advance!

```
create or alter proc test_proc  as
begin
set nocount on
-- this piece of code has the new databases 
if object_id('tempdb..#dbNames') is not null drop table #dbNames
create table #dbNames (dbName varchar(1000), id int)
insert into #dbNames(dbName, id) values ('new_database2', 1),('new_database3', 2)
insert into #dbNames(dbName, id) values ('new_database8', 3),('new_database9', 4)

-- this one has the sample functions
if object_id('tempdb..#dbFunctions') is not null drop table #dbFunctions
create table #dbFunctions (funText nvarchar(max))
insert into #dbFunctions (funText) values('create function [schema1].[funTest1] (@param1 varchar(50))
returns table as
return
(
select * from [curr_database1].[schema1].[funTest1](@param1)
union
select * from [curr_database2].[schema1].[funTest1](@param1)
)'),
('create function [schema2].[funTest2] (@param1 varchar(50), @param2 varchar(100))
returns table as
return
(
select * from [curr_database4].[schema2].[funTest2](@param1, @param2)
union
select * from [curr_database5].[schema2].[funTest2](@param1, @param2)
)')

    -- declare variables and assign value for @frmStr variable (for testing purposes)
    declare @str nvarchar(max)
    declare @dbName varchar(100)
    declare @frmStr varchar(100) = '[curr_database1]'

    -- get the total count of the databases and the functions to iterate and replace the string
    declare @dbCnt int = (select count(id) from #dbNames)
    declare @fnCnt int = (select count(*) from #dbFunctions)    

    while @dbCnt > 0
    begin
        set @dbname = (select dbname from #dbnames where id = @dbcnt)

        while @fnCnt > 0
            begin
            -- this is where I would need to replace the code
            select @str = replace(funText, @frmStr, @dbName) from #dbFunctions 
            select @str

            set @fnCnt = @fnCnt - 1
        end

        set @dbCnt = @dbCnt - 1
    end
end
```

Comment: Please use the code formatting button to edit your question's code.

Comment: Sounds like you would be better off using synonyms here.

Comment: Yep, seems like a fun test indeed. I'm guessing this is not a one time thing, but should be repeated every x time, right?

Comment: yes @TabAlleman, I want to alter the functions and then create snapshots based on the altered script.

Comment: @ZoharPeled.. right...this is going to get repeated multiple times.

Comment: I agree 10000000% with @Larnu here. Create synonyms and update your code to use those synonyms. Then the next time you need to make these kinds of changes you simply change your synonyms and all of your functions just work. Or perhaps you might consider figuring out why you are constantly needing to change the source databases. Seems like a pretty serious design flaw to me.

Comment: @TabAlleman for funTest1, it has to replace both the databases [curr_database1] and [curr_database2]. Similarly, it has to do for funTest2 and all other functions. The replace function that I have will replace only the [curr_database1] to [new_database2]. how to search all the databases that start with "curr" and replace until .(dot) ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362260/a-sql-query-to-select-a-string-between-two-known-strings

Comment: @TabAlleman.. thanks for the link. I looked at that yesterday itself and couldn't use it because of the one-time search and static one. Also, it is not working for multiple searches in the same function

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about one-time and static, and why that prevents you from using this technique.

Comment: @TabAlleman I have given the similar code here as "select substring(funText, charindex(@frmStr, '.'), charindex('.',funText) - charindex(@frmStr, funText) + len('.')) from #dbFunctions "

Comment: Am getting the below result. "create function [schema1].[funTest1] (@param1 varchar(50))  returns table as  return  (  select * from new_database9.[schema1].[funTest1](@param1)  union  select * from [curr_database2].[schema1].[funTest1](@param1)  ) create function [schema2].[funTest2] (@param1 varchar(50), @param2 varchar(100))  returns table as  return  (  select * from [curr_database4].[schema2].[funTest2](@param1, @param2)  union  select * from [curr_database5].[schema2].[funTest2](@param1, @param2)  )"

Comment: This is not replacing all the databases. Am I doing anything wrong? can you please help? Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to read the code in your comments, can you edit your question instead and format the code to make it easy to read?

Answer (score 0):

Your actual goal isn't clear, but to answer the question you asked, you can use REPLACE functions in the query to syscomments that you used to get the code in the first place:

```
REPLACE(
  REPLACE([FunctionTextColumn],'curr_database1','new_database2')
,'curr_database2','new_database3'
)
```

Comment: the suggested replace function can be used if I'm sure of the curr_database1 and curr_database2, etc names. In my scenario, I don't know the database names and it would need to be handled dynamically.

Comment: Sooo.... parameters then? You're going to need to know the names at some point ...

Comment: @artoflearning in that case you've left some necessary details out of your question.   Add them to the question and I'll update the answer accordingly.   As things currently stand, this answers the question you asked.

Comment: @TabAlleman sure. let me change the code as a test script and post it here

Comment: @TabAlleman I have added the test script. Can you please have a look and suggest? Thanks