# T-SQL Extract string between two known strings

Tags: sql, t-sql, substring, ssms

I have the following Text:

"Original ----- The cow jumped over the moon ----- 20200723 --NEW-- The cow jumped over the sun ----- "

I'm trying to write a t-sql query that will extract everything between the string "Original ----- " and the following " ----- ", so my outcome would be:

"Original ----- The cow jumped over the moon ----- "

I've tried writing something like this:

```
declare @Text nvarchar(max) = 'Original ----- The cow jumped over the moon ----- 20200723 --NEW-- The cow jumped over the sun ----- '
select SUBSTRING(@Text, CHARINDEX('Original ----- ', @Text)
, CHARINDEX(' ----- ',@Text) - CHARINDEX('Original ----- ', @Text) + Len(' ----- '))
```

But it just returns `Original -----`.
Please help!

Comment: `CHARINDEX(' ----- ',@Text) - CHARINDEX('Original ----- ', @Text)` finds the same occurrence of `' ----- '` twice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A SQL Query to select a string between two known strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362260/a-sql-query-to-select-a-string-between-two-known-strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CHARINDEX` [has a third, optional argument](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_charindex.asp), which is the start. Modify your query as follows to begin looking for --- after the first occurence.

```
select SUBSTRING(@Text, CHARINDEX('Original ----- ', @Text)
, CHARINDEX(' ----- ',@Text, CHARINDEX('Original ----- ', @Text) + len('Original ----- '))) + '-----';
```

[A quick Fiddle to demonstrate](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a2e97/11).

Answer (score 1):

You could rely on the fact that `Original -----`  is a fixed number of characters and hard code that value into your code. Then either use a `where` clause or a `case` expression to only apply it to those starting with `Original -----`

```
select 'Original ----- '+substring(col,16,charindex( '-----',col, 16)-11)
from t
where col like 'Original -----%';
```